# webkit not working on chrome

Tags: css, webkit

Until last month or so everything worked perfectly, but since one of chrome or webkit updates, it seems that something went wrong without me changing a thing in the code.

i build a couple of dives and made them rounded with webkit css, for a month they don't get rounded any more on chrome, on safari it works well.

```
.hostpie {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  width:148px;
  height:300px;
  -moz-border-radius:150px;
  -webkit-border-radius:150px;
  border-radius:150px;
  -webkit-border-radius:150px 0 0 150px;
  -webkit-transform-origin:right center;
}
```

Comment: you should not use the vendor prefixes in a production environment for exactly this reason.

Comment: im afraid i do not follow, what does it mean? what is vendor prefixes? how should i do it then?

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like? It works as expected for me.

Comment: @Bazzz - Vendor prefixes are just fine as long as you understand how cascading works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vendor-prefixed properties should appear *before* the CSS property, as even if your newer version of Chrome supports the un-prefixed version, it will use `-webkit-border-radius: 150px 0 0 150px;` because it appears last. Putting the official CSS property last ensures that it will be applied by browsers that correctly support it.

Also `-webkit-border-radius: 150px;` and `-webkit-border-radius: 150px 0 0 150px;` are doing two different things. The latter is targeting the top-left corner & the bottom-left corner while the former is targeting all four corners. I don't understand why you have both?

Try changing the order

```
.hostpie {
 width:148px;
 height:300px;
-moz-border-radius:150px;
-webkit-border-radius:150px 0 0 150px; /* top left -- bottom left */
 border-radius:150px; /* CSS Property last */
}
```

[Vendor prefixes and the cascade](http://emps.l-c-n.com/notebook/css-vendor-prefixes-and-the-cascade)